# Calculating viewing angle (2D) between polygons and points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, point, coordinates

I am looking for a solution to the following problem.

I have several points (for example houses) and several polygons (eg forests).
Seen from the houses, I can see the forests within a certain angle. This angle is different for each house. To calculate this angle, I need the points on the polygon where the angle of view is maximum. ie the extreme left point of the forest and the extreme right point of the forest. I could calculate the angle with these two points.
This is about 1,500 points (houses), so that the drawing of lines and the coordination of the endpoints is unfortunately not an option.

I hope the drawing shows what I'm looking for.

[image]

Is it possible to determine the coordinates of the two outermost visible points of the forest for each building?

How I can determine the angles?

I use ArcGIS Desktop with a Standard license without any extensions.

Comment: What software are you using?  What extensions or plugins do you have available? Calculating visibility is simple enough with the right tools, at which point computing the furthest angles is also easy.  Without those tools, it's still fairly simple, but you need to be prepared to do a great deal of trigonometry.

Comment: I use ArcGIS with a standard license without any extensions. But I could also switch to qgis if there are the necessary functions.
Dealing with trigonometry is not a problem, it does not have to be done in GIS. I can also use excel for that.

Comment: No, you can't use Excel for this, since it cannot access the geometry. If trig isn't a problem, I suggest you just get started, computing the angle from each observation point to every polygon vertex, identifying the gap which exceeds 180°, capturing the minimum and maximum from that gap, and the center from the minimum and maximum. You've framed the problem, so now it's time to code. If you run into a problem update the question with details.

Comment: I guess my description was a misunderstanding. I know how to calculate trigonometry.What I don't know is how I can coordinate the polygon vertex. Therefore I do need help.

Comment: My idea was to calculate the angle. For that I need the length of the three sides of the triangle. in order to calculate these I need the coordinates of the polygon vertices.
The real question is, how do I get the coordinates of the vertices.
Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` documentation shows how to iterate shapefile rows, and using `SHAPE@XY` field token will give you a list of coords to walk.

Comment: You don't need three points, just two. Compute bearing from first point to first vertex, and then compute min/max of vertices from there on (wrapping by twoPi as necessary). Coding questions here are expected to contain code, so you need to set up the nested poly by point query loop at a minimum.

Comment: @vince I think your second comment provided enough insight to post as an answer. It provides a conceptual approach, while leaving the coding up to the OP.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If your "real question is, how do I get the coordinates of the vertices" then I think that you should use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it to make that the single question that you wish to ask.

Comment: If you decide to ask about code to do this we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I guess they showed me that my question was much to general. Therefore i think i will ask a new question in a new post that is more concrete.